# on_member_join not working for welcome message

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

Trying to make a simple welcome print when a user joins:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member) : 
    print ("new member joined")
bot.run("token bwahahhaha")
```

**ALL INTENTS ARE ENABLED, INCLUDING ON THE DEV PORTAL**

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

and I'm getting no errors, and no prints.

Comment: Hi. Can you post your full code?

Comment: That is my full code.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it shows in a channel you should go to settings/settingschannels and choose the channel
then
you should to use a await not a print

```
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = member.guild.system_channel
    await channel.send(f"hello {member.display_name}")

bot.run("token")
```

if you want it looks better you can use an embed

Comment: It won't read the event, even though it should. I'm not sure what to do.